# Prometheus config file hosts not listed in grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have the following config in /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml

```
global:
    scrape_interval: 5s
    evaluation_interval: 5s
scrape_configs:
    - job_name: prometheus
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['localhost:9090']
    - job_name: kktix-redis-1
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['localhost:9121']
    - job_name: kktix-redis-2
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['localhost:9122']
    - job_name: captcha-001
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['localhost:9123']
    - job_name: captcha-002
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['localhost:9124']
    - job_name: kktix-cache-001
      static_configs:
            - targets: ['localhost:9125']
    - job_name: kktix-cache-002
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['localhost:9126']
    - job_name: kktix-data-001
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['localhost:9127']
    - job_name: kktix-data-002
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['localhost:9128']
    - job_name: register-queue-001
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['localhost:9129']
    - job_name: register-queue-002
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['localhost:9130']
    - job_name: receipt-001
      static_configs:
          - targets: ['localhost:9131']
```

On this prometheus server, i am running several redis_exporter processes with different ports (9121, 9122,...9131)  to access and collect stats on remote redis instances located on AWS elasticache. I am using Grafana as the UI dashboard for viewing graphs. However, there are only 4 nodes showing in griffin based on the config above, which are the nodes with ports 1921, 1922, 1928, and 1929. Other configured nodes above do not show in griffin for some reason.

All the ports and appropriate elasticache endpoints have been correctly executed and tested. So not sure why griffin is only displaying 4 nodes. I have tried clearing cache in the web browser, restart griffin, restart prometheus, re-install both prometheus and grafana and none of these things seem to be helping.

Any advise on this issue?

Comment: Do the all the configured hosts show up in the "targets" list on `<<prometheus-server-ip>>:9100/targets` ? Are they up? Do you see the metrics when you query the `/graphs` endpoint of your Prometheus server?

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with the endpoints. Cannot telnet to the redis there. Thanks.